# Jquery ajax call throws empty JS exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This function works on one page but not another. I've added all sorts of logging to try to find the error, but cannot. The output of this code on the broken page is:

```
[13:59:56.427] "here"
[13:59:56.428] "beforesend: /admin/test.html?server=eferbelly&port=24466&username=akilandy&password=vkjvkc9776A"
[13:59:56.428] "fileName=undefined"
[13:59:56.428] "lineNumber=undefined"
[13:59:56.428] "columnNumber=undefined"
[13:59:56.428] "here6"
```

That tells me it's getting into the exception handler, completely skipping my ajax() call, but it's not telling me the exception.

```
function test(server, port, username, password, spanId) {
  spanId = "#" + spanId;
  $(spanId).html("<img src='/images/ajax-small.gif'/>");
  console.log("here");
  try {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      url: "/admin/test.html?server=" + server + "&port=" + port + "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
      success: function(json){
        console.log("here2");
        if (json.httpStatus == "200") {
          // Change the image to show success
          $(spanId).html("<img src='/images/accept.png' title='success'/>");
        }
        else {
          console.log("here7");
          // Change the image to show failure
          $(spanId).html("<span style='color:#b22222;'>" + json.httpStatus +"</span>&nbsp;<img style='vertical-align: middle;' src='/images/cancel.png' title='placeholder'/>");
        }
        console.log("here8");
        $(spanId).tooltip({ content: json.msg});
      },
      // Display the URL
      beforeSend: function(b,c,d) {console.log("beforesend: " + c.url);},
      error: function(b,c,d) {console.log("here5");}
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    for (var i in e)
      console.log(i + "=" + i[e]);
  }
  console.log("here6");
}
```

What could I do further to debug this?

**UPDATE: Output of code on a working page**

Here's the output of the exact same code but on the page where it is working:

```
[15:01:20.158] "here"
[15:01:20.159] "beforesend: /admin/test.html?server=eferbelly&port=24466&username=akilandy&password=vkjvkc9776A"
[15:01:20.159] "here6"
[15:01:21.661] GET https://localhost/images/accept.png [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
[15:01:21.599] "here2"
[15:01:21.600] "here8"
```

So it obviously gets through the ajax call with flying colors. No errors, nothing. How can I find the problem on the page where it doesn't work?

Comment: Your error logging is messed up. It should be `console.log(i + "=" + e[i]);`. Not `i.e`. Or just log the object and read its content. `console.log(e);`

Comment: Why are you doing `for (var i in e)`?  Just do `console.log(e)` (or `console.dir(e)`).  P.S. `i.e` is incorrect.  `e` is your object, and `i` is the index, so it's `e[i]`.

Comment: "*completely skipping my ajax() call*" if that were the case, it wouldn't have logged beforeSend.

Comment: I would remove the try/catch and use the browser console to debug it.

Comment: When I do `console.log(e)`, the output is `[ObjectError]`. Not very helpful. That's why I tried the `for (var i in e)` bit. Anyway, changing the code to `console.log(i + "=" + e[i])` doesn't change the output. filename, linenumber, and columnnumber are all undefined. I still have no clues!

Comment: Are you debugging in IE? is this problem only happening in IE? Most modern browsers would allow you to expand the ObjectError to see it's properties from the console.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 24.4.0 (extended support release). When I inspect the ObjectError, there's nothing of interest. `message` is `""` and the other properties are `undefined`, as I previously mentioned.